# I've downloaded Wine from Winehq (Linux 20.04, stable version), but I'm not sure that it's installed

Tags: 20.04, wine, configuration

I've downloaded Wine from Winehq (Linux 20.04, stable version). The download seemed to work (everything unpacked OK), but I don't see the directory structure that the instructions seem to expect. I don't get wine as an option in Open With and from the command line I get  file not found.

Comment: What exactly did you download and what did you exactly do? Did you follow the instructions here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu ? Please update (edit) your question with more information.

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for the latest version of wine, undo all that you have done and install the version from the Ubuntu repos.